# SharePoint 2010 web analytics storage usage

Tags: sharepoint-server

Our SharePoint 2010 web analytics display 0 value for the last couple of weeks, therefore i deleted the Web analytic service in CA. Then i created a new web analytics service with new databases (ReportingDB and StagingDB) then web analytics created successfully with new databases.

Then, i want to use the old ReportingDB and StagingDB database which still in the database server via CA and modified successfully. However, it still display the data from the new databases although i have modified to used the old databases. I have confirm that SharePoint 2010 web analytic is now binding to the old database using the following powershell

```
Get-SPServiceApplication | Where {$_.TypeName -like "Web Analytics*"} | fl
```

Thank you

Comment: Did u clear the configuration cache on all servers?

Comment: yup, i did clear configuration cache and iisreset but still not fix the issue